# How to call a same JavaScript function on multiple HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, html

I have written a function that removes HTML table row from top as it gets out of view-port while scrolling down. The functions works fine for the first row. However, it does not work for the subsequent rows. How can I apply this function to all rows? I want each row to be removed from DOM once it gets out of view-port while scrolling. Thank you!

Here is my code:

```js
var topRowPos = document.getElementById("topRowPos");

function removeRow (rowId){
    var row = document.getElementById(rowId);
    var rect = row.getBoundingClientRect();
    var rowTop = Math.ceil(rect.top);
    topRowPos.innerHTML = rowTop;
    
    // remove row if out of viewport
    if (rowTop <= 0){
        row.remove();
    }
}

document.onscroll = function (){
    removeRow('row1'); // works for first row
    // removeRow('row2'); doesn't work for subsequent rows
}
```

```css
body{height:1000px;}

table{border-collapse:collapse;}

td {height:20px; width:50px; text-align:center;}
```

```html
<table border=1 id="myTable">
   <tr id="row1"> <td>1</td> </tr>
   <tr id="row2"> <td>2</td> </tr>
   <tr id="row3"> <td>3</td> </tr>
   <tr id="row4"> <td>4</td> </tr>
   <tr id="row5"> <td>5</td> </tr>
   <tr id="row6"> <td>6</td> </tr>
   <tr id="row7"> <td>7</td> </tr>
   <tr id="row8"> <td>8</td> </tr>
   <tr id="row9"> <td>9</td> </tr>
   <tr id="row10"> <td>10</td> </tr>
</table>

<br>
Row Pos: <span id="topRowPos"></span><br>
```

Comment: The first thing to do is to get rid of the ids, then you could get familiar with the [HTMLTableElement interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement), specifically with its [deleteRow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/deleteRow) method.

Comment: And [`IntersectionObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver)

Comment: @Teemu Thank you. It does not work with deleteRow as well. Only works for the first row and doesn't delete the subsequent rows. I have just tested.

Comment: [No](https://jsfiddle.net/xyjt4Ldq/)?

Comment: @Teemu Thank you! It is helpful but it deletes row even if I scroll up. I was trying to achieve row deletion when scroll down.

Comment: Even deleting 1st row also giving below error. In this line only it is getting null. var row = document.getElementById(rowId);. Can u please check on that. Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's just an example, that `deleteRow` works. You've to still detect when the row is scrolled out of the view.

Comment: @Boney Id of first row is being given as an argument to function removeRow and when this row is deleted there is no reference to id and it produces error.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you very much! Intersection API has everything I was looking for.